# Setting up 802.1x WiFi

Tags: wireless

I just installed Ubuntu on an 'of the self' Lenovo machine. I can use the web just fine from home, but at the University I cannot connect to the networks. After some research I suspect that 802.1x protocol is not installed or not activated. I have read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Network802.1xAuthentication) but for some reason if have a directory at `/etc/wpa_supplicant/` but no file called `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`, and none of the files inside that directory looks similar to the file in the site.

So my questions:

- How do I check if 802.1x is installed?
- How do I check if 802.1x is active?
- Can I run a test from home to make sure that everything is ready? I want to check it so I don't have to be there try it, and if not look for a computer an set up stuff again while I should be studying.

If relevant:

- I have Ubuntu 13.04, 32 bit.
- runs on a Lenovo G550
- `xsupplicant` is not a recognized command.
- The files in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/` are: `action_wpa.sh`, `functions_wpa.sh`, `ifupdown.sh`.

Comment: At home, do you use WiFi or a cable connection?

Comment: WiFi, without encryption. And I just played with the settings at my router and found that I can activate 802.1x encryption, so that solved the third question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the necessary parts are installed by default in Ubuntu desktop versions. You can check:

```
modinfo cfg80211
modinfo mac80211
```

If you get any information at all, the parts are there. They will only be invoked as a dependency of some wireless driver and will then appear as loaded modules:

```
lsmod
```

I suspect that there is a problem with your wireless driver and that may be a separate question.